# Simplification of polynomials arising from snub hyperbolic tilings

Tags: geometry, polynomials, hyperbolic-geometry

Lately I've been generating SVG files of uniform hyperbolic tilings in the Poincaré disc model (PDM). The results are usually very pretty.

[image: Snub triheptagonal tiling]

To generate snub tilings $sr\{p,q\}$, like $sr\{7,3\}$ above, I need to compute the circumradius of the central polygon (in red above) *as seen in the PDM*. I do not want to derive this constant numerically, but rather as the root of a polynomial, which is possible because I am not using *hyperbolic* distances. I have found that, for general $p,q$ with $\frac1p+\frac1q<\frac12$, the circumradius of the central $p$-gon is $\frac{\sqrt x-\sqrt{x-4}}2$ where $x$ is the largest real root of the quartic polynomial
$$(a-b)^2x^4\\
+8(a-b)(2a^2-2ab-a+2b)x^3\\
+8(12a^4-18a^3b-11a^3+12a^2b^2+29a^2b+2a^2-24ab^2-12ab+12b^2)x^2\\
+32(8a^5-2a^4b-10a^4+8a^3b^2+8a^3b+3a^3-24a^2b^2-10a^2b+24ab^2+4ab-8b^2)x\\
+16(4a^3+4a^2b-3a^2-8ab+4b)^2$$
and $a=\sin^2\frac\pi p$ and $b=\cos^2\frac\pi q$. A Python implementation can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Dounreay/blob/bb92c10892b8146c4be4ae1c2edd0c5a1443b33f/heptille/pdmconst.py#L63).

My question lies in *simplifying* the coefficients of this polynomial, themselves polynomials in $a$ and $b$, so to minimise the operation count (and hence time and potential rounding error too) à la [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/973787/357390). The $x^4$, $x^3$ and constant coefficients look simplified enough; I'm most concerned about the $x^2$ and $x$ coefficients. I've been perturbing up to three monomials at once in hopes of getting a neat factorisation of the perturbed polynomial, and this is the best I've got so far:
$$8(12a^4+a^3-ab-(3ab+2a-3b)(6a^2-4ab-a+4b))x^2$$
$$32(a^3(4a-3)(2a-1)-2b(a-1)^2(a^2-4ab-2a+4b))x$$

> But can I do better than this? Can I reduce the complexity further? Is it possible to leverage intermediate results for the other coefficients in reducing the complexity?

Comment: Oh hey, you make all those illustrations of tilings on Wikipedia! Thank you and keep up the good work.

Comment: Indeed a great work! On the contrary, I have a question. Do you have a code somewhere which generates these semi regular tiling. I am deeply interested and would like to learn more!